# How can I create a horizontal scrolling table without using display: block; overflow-x: auto?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm building an app that has a lot of tables. Some are horizontally long so I want to add horizontal scrolling to them if they extent outside of the page.

I googled around for a solution and they all point to using `display: block; overflow-x: auto;` on the table. This works for tables wider than the screen but now that tables are set as `display:block;` instead of the default `display: table;` the table cells are all squished together and the table doesn't maintain its natural 100% width which makes tables that aren't wider than the screen took horrible and squished to the left of the page.

It seems like I can either have tables with less columns look good and have tables with lots of columns go off the page, or have tables with less columns look bad and tables with lots of columns nice and responsive. But there doesn't seem to be a solution for both.

The tables are user generated so I cant manually set the css for each table myself.

So is there a way to actaully keep `display: table` on a table so it behaves like a table and have the table scroll horizontally if its wider than the page?

**Update:**

JS fiddles:

[With display: block; overflow-x: auto](https://jsfiddle.net/fooraoqz/)

[Without display: block; overflow-x: auto](https://jsfiddle.net/f52e6ws8/)

Sorry the CSS is in the html but users will be using WYSIWYG editors to make the tables so thats the way it will be in the app.

Comment: can you share some code? I cant reproduce your issue

Comment: @ChathuraBuddhika I added 2 js fiddles to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use container `<div>` to wrap tables and apply overflow property for that div.

```css
.container{
  display:block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: center;">text</td>
   <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: center;">text</td>
   <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: center;">text</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="container">
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-beerus"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45152-v1474530116-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-beerus-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-goten"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45176-v1474530282-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-goten-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-trunks"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45184-v1474530347-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-trunks-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-ultimate-gohan"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45168-v1474530235-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-ultimate-gohan-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-vegeta"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45192-v1474530403-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-vegeta-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-videl"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45200-v1474530470-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-videl-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-whis"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45160-v1474530187-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-whis-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="container">
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">head
    <br>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-beerus"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45152-v1474530116-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-beerus-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-goten"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45176-v1474530282-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-goten-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-trunks"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45184-v1474530347-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-trunks-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-ultimate-gohan"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45168-v1474530235-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-ultimate-gohan-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-vegeta"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45192-v1474530403-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-vegeta-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-videl"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45200-v1474530470-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-videl-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 14.2857%; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://guidir.com/guides/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/awakening-medals/bog-whis"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/guidir/item-value-images/thumb_45160-v1474530187-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle-awakening-medals-bog-whis-image.png" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <br>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can ceck the results by clicking "Run" button and then "Full Page" link

Comment: Thats a good idea but it doesn't work for me the same way it works when I run your snippet. Your code has the top table stay in the same spot and the scroll looks like it just moves the table content. In my code it moves all the content in the div https://jsfiddle.net/zv65jazd/

Comment: Its not working on jsfiddle. Thats an issue with jsfiddle. try copy that code in to a html file and run. It should work

Comment: Does the same thing on my app. Not sure why. Can you add another wide table under the second table to see if it scrolls each table separately, both tables or all the content in the div.

Comment: I updated the code as you requested. Even in jsfiddle it works perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/zb3m37vw/
You should add container divs for each table separately.

Comment: Unfortunately that fix wont work in my case. The tables are made by users in a WYSIWYG editor. There is no way for me to wrap each individual table in a div

Comment: Ended up monkey patching the WYSIWYG editor so the tables have divs around them. Looks like this does the job thanks.

Comment: @Rob Okay, Happy to know. :)

Comment: This works - but what do you do in the case of having 0 results in the table and having tooltips on table headers click? They produce a vertical scrollbar whereas you cannot prevent it (overflow-x:auto and overflow-y:visible dont work together -> both become auto)